# DB Access - change record with dropdown value

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a dropdown with a query where I get 4 values (OS: WIn7, Win10, Win8, WinVista) from a table.

I now can go to all my Servers and I see their Value since I did this with filling in the ID (I have a relationship in the tbl Server with a fk_OS from tbl OS)

When I change the value in the dropbox, it changes the table OS instead of the value in the table server.

Has anyone an idea how to change this?

Comment: A detailed diagram of your table structure would be useful, including the relationships...

Comment: at this moment there are just two table

tbl_Server
pk_ID
Name
fkOS


tbl_OS
pk_ID
NameOS

tbl_OS.pk_OS has a one to many relation to tbl_Server.fk_OS

in the form I have a getOS query bound to the Combobox

What I want is that I can go torugh my Server and the Combobox Shows the OS of that Server.
This works.
But if I want to change it for one record, it overwrites the record in the tbl_OS itself 
for example:

system01
OS: Win7

now I choose Win10 from the Combobox -> all Systems with Win7 have now Win10. In the tbl_OS the record Win7 was overwritten with value Win10

Comment: Maybe this helps a bit more:

I want to use my Form to edit Systeminfos
In the end I will Display all the attributes of a System in this form and I want to be able to Change the System records values with dropdowns